# how to copy/clone div and it's javascript functions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have this code that repeats div "clone" and retrieve data by ajax from a php file

how can i make the repeated input retrieve data too not the first input only

```
<div class="input" id="itemRows">

                     <div class="clone">
                     <?php $x = 1; ?>
                         <style>
                         .txtHint1 {
                             width:95%;
                             padding:10px 6px;
                             border-bottom:solid 3px #06C;
                             background-color:#f1f1f1;
                             margin-right:5px;
                         }
                         </style>
                      <script>
                        function <?php echo 'showUser'.$x;?>(str)
                        {
                        if (str=="")
                          {
                          document.getElementById("<?php echo 'txtHint'.$x;?>").innerHTML="";
                          return;
                          } 
                        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                          }
                        else
                          {// code for IE6, IE5
                          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                          }
                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                          {
                          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                            {
                            document.getElementById("<?php echo 'txtHint'.$x;?>").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                          }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","searchuser/getuser.php?clientmergedid="+str,true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                        }
                      </script>
                         <input onchange="<?php echo 'showUser'.$x;?>(this.value)" type="text" class="clientphone" placeholder="رقم العميل" name="clientmergedid[]" />
                        <input type="text" class="clientdes" placeholder="صفة العميل" name="clientmergeddes[]" />
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                        <div id="<?php echo 'txtHint'.$x;?>" class="<?php echo 'txtHint'.$x; $x++;?>">بيانات العميل</div>
                        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
                     </div>
                    <a href="#" class="add clientadd" rel=".clone">إضافة المزيد</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                      var removeLink = ' <a class="remove" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().slideUp(function(){ $(this).remove() }); return false">إزالة</a>';
                    $('a.add').relCopy({ append: removeLink});  
                    });
                    </script>
                    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

                    <!--<input class="add clientadd" rel=".clone" onClick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="جديد" />-->
                    <div class="clearfloat"></div>

                 </div>
```

i have Googled about it but i didn't reach any thing

Answer (score 0):

You are already using jQuery, you can clone the div and it's event handlers if you use the deep clone version of `clone`. Something like this:

```
var clonedDiv = $('#existingDiv').clone(true); //where the true param indicates to clone data and events.
```

[See full documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Answer (score 0):

Cf http://api.jquery.com/clone/ :

```
$(div).clone(true, true);
```

Comment: i still can not repeat the function neither the onchange action